# Menu Available across the whole app

Tags: java, android, xml

Im trying to get my menu accessible across my app with out having to add the XML code to all my activities as well as the code in all the classes.

I already have a "BaseController" class that handle some aspects of the menu like the TabHost and text etc but I am unable to get the menu extrapolated so it can be used across the app without having to retype all my code over and over again?

HomeActivity.class

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseController {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate has been called");

    menu();
    mDrawerLayout =(CustomDrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.home_activity);
    left = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_menu);
    menu_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menuImageButton)
}

private void openMenu() {
    if (hasLoggedInBefore() == false) {
        goToLogin();
    } else {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(left);
    }
}
```

activity_home.xml

```
<com.myapp.app.ui.CustomDrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/home_activity"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    layout="@layout/home_screen_items"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_menu"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/bob_orange6">

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/menuTabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/menu_tab1_tab"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Tab1 Tab Text"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/menu_tab2_tab"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Tab2 Tab Text"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/menu_tab3_tab"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Tab3 Tab Text"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

as you can see above my menu is in the HomeActivity XML and if i try add it using the  tag, the menu overlays the content and does not collapse.

The only way it works is if i do it the way i have above.

my BaseController.java

```
public class BaseController extends Activity {
CustomDrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
RelativeLayout left;

    public void menu(){
    final TabHost menuTab = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.menuTabs);
    menuTab.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec tab1_tab_menu = menuTab.newTabSpec("Tab1");
    tab1_tab_menu.setContent(R.id.menu_tab1_tab);
    tab1_tab_menu.setIndicator("Tab1");
    menuTab.addTab(tab1_tab_menu);

    TabHost.TabSpec tab2_tab_menu = menuTab.newTabSpec("Tab2");
    tab2_tab_menu.setContent(R.id.menu_tab2_tab);
    tab2_tab_menu.setIndicator("Tab2");
    menuTab.addTab(tab2_tab_menu);

    TabHost.TabSpec tab3_tab_menu = menuTab.newTabSpec("Tab3");
    tab3_tab_menu.setContent(R.id.menu_tab3_tab);
    tab3_tab_menu.setIndicator("Tab3");
    menuTab.addTab(tab3_tab_menu);
}
}
```

incase its needed i have include the CustomDrawerLayout code

CustomDrawerLayout.java

```
public class CustomDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout{

public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
}
```

The idea is to have it in the baseController class and pretty much call a method in the onCreate in a specific activity that i want the menu in as well as say  in the xml for that Activity and the menu is basically there with the same content etc?

Been battling with this for a couple days now. Help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can solve that using one activity that acts like a controller for the fragments. You load the fragments in the screen when you need them (like different screens). You load your menu fragment once and so it is accessible on every screen.

Comment: use fragments instead of other activities , and do the menu,communication between fragments and other universal stuff in Main activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Implemention for UrMenu should be done in BaseControllerActivity, and all other activities in our application must inhert this BaseControllerActivity. Then you can use that menu, and you can override if want to customize onClick of menu's.